# Having many subdomains with SSL--best practices?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ssl, virtualhost, ssl-certificate

I have a site that has many subdomains (one for each client). The content for each subdomain will be different, pulling different data, different layouts etc, so I don't think I can just alias one directory to many different sub domains. My question is, what's the best practice for doing this? Each subdomain will need SSL. My setup is

- Amazon EC2 (ubuntu)
- Wildcard SSL for my domain (*.mydomain.com)
- Apache 2
- PHP (LAMP)

Currently, I'm just creating a new entry into "/etc/hosts" and an appropriate spot in the web root (ie /var/www/abc.mydomain.com, /var/www/def.mydomain.com, etc). I've just discovered that I'll need a unique IP for each subdomain, and that's tricky with EC2 as they limit you to the number you can have (unless you jump through some hoops). Right now I have about 10 subdomains, which is manageable, but theoretically I could have thousands.

Am I doing it the only way possible or is there a better way I should investigate?

Comment: If you have a single wildcard certificate that works for all your domains, then you shouldn't really need multiple IP addresses.  Normally you only really need on IP per certificate.

Comment: I've learned a lot since this--and yes, the best solution was to get a wildcard DNS certificate that covers all subdomains with just one IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you are adding them to /etc/hosts?  If the hostname resolves, that should be plenty for a more general purpose.

I like the directory structure you are using and that is very similar to any approach I would use.  Additionally, I recommend specifying separate `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` files for each subdomain.

Zoredache makes a fantastic point on IPs, as that your wildcard certificate should eliminate the need for multiple IPs when adding subdomains.  Additionally, there is a newer [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI) feature that eliminates the need for an IP per each separate SSL certificate.

If you have thousands, that is typically where you might consider writing a script for managing the adding or removing VirtualHosts, sharing content, redirects, and other potential solutions.  Options are going to be based on your exact needs at that time.

If you are talking about multiple user systems, the approaches are fundamentally different as well.  For example, each domain would be in /home/user/public_html or /home/user/www.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on SNI. I wasn't aware of that option.

Comment: Thanks Warner, I just assumed I had to set each up in /etc/hosts. I don't have to? I'll investigate that and SNI. Thanks very much for your input and suggestions.

Comment: No.  Typically /etc/hosts would be used for mapping fake hostnames for local use or changing how something would otherwise resolve locally.  The primary server hostname would live in /etc/hosts but as far as every `VirtualHost`, I wouldn't.  You're welcome.